# JAXWS method parameter data types won't change

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

I published two endpoints

```
        Endpoint ep = Endpoint.create(new HotelWS());
        ep.publish("http://127.0.0.1:1000/ra/hotel");

        Endpoint ep1 = Endpoint.create(new RoomTypeWS());
        ep1.publish("http://127.0.0.1:1000/ra/roomtype");
```

this is the method in RoomTypeWS class

```
@WebMethod
public boolean add(RoomType roomType) {
    return super.$add(roomType);
}
```

and this is the method in HotelWS class

```
@WebMethod
public boolean add(Hotel obj) {
    return super.$add(obj);
}
```

but in client application both methods parameter type is Hotel. But if i publish only one endpoint only it works fine.

This is how RoomTypeWS.add and HotelWS.add methods generated in client application

```
public interface RoomTypeWS {
    /**
     * 
     * @param arg0
     * @return
     *     returns boolean
     */
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(targetNamespace = "")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "add", targetNamespace = "http://services/", className = "net.codegen.reservationagentrestservice.soap_services.Add")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "addResponse", targetNamespace = "http://services/", className = "net.codegen.reservationagentrestservice.soap_services.AddResponse")
    @Action(input = "http://services/RoomTypeWS/addRequest", output = "http://services/RoomTypeWS/addResponse")
    public boolean add(
        @WebParam(name = "arg0", targetNamespace = "")
        Hotel arg0);

}


public interface HotelWS {


    /**
     * 
     * @param arg0
     * @return
     *     returns boolean
     */
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(targetNamespace = "")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "add", targetNamespace = "http://services/", className = "net.codegen.reservationagentrestservice.soap_services.Add")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "addResponse", targetNamespace = "http://services/", className = "net.codegen.reservationagentrestservice.soap_services.AddResponse")
    @Action(input = "http://services/HotelWS/addRequest", output = "http://services/HotelWS/addResponse")
    public boolean add(
        @WebParam(name = "arg0", targetNamespace = "")
        Hotel arg0);

}
```

Comment: What do you mean datatype won't change ? Do you get those endpoints published succesfully ?

Comment: Yes, after endpoints published. I generated classes in client application using wsimport command. As shown above, in RoomTypeWS, ```public boolean add(@WebParam(name = "arg0", targetNamespace = "")
        Hotel arg0);``` should be ```@WebParam(name = "arg0", targetNamespace = "")
        RoomType arg0);``` But it is not.

Comment: This is the top down approach, you shoud inspect your wsdl carefully before generating the artifact classes, it could be that you simply generate class based on wrong endpoint. You should post your wsdl/xsd also.